# VideoWriter result in a corrupted video when its set on 2fps

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, video-capture, frame-rate

I am trying to read a video, crop each frame from top and bottom and then write back each frame and also write them in to a video in mp4 format.
The input video is at 2fps and it is also in mp4 format.
The frames are saving properly but I can not write them as a 2fps video. I have tried other frame rates such as 1fps, 3fps, 5fps, 10fps and even 25fps. All of them work properly except 2fps, which result in a corrupted video (either its not showing any fame except the fist frame, or its just displaying a green screen)
Any thoughts or comments will be appreciated:

```
reader = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4') 
cropped_video = os.path.join('video_crop.mp4')
cropped_frames = os.path.join('video/')

if (reader.isOpened() == False):
    print('Error while trying to open video. Plese check again...')
else:   
    # get the frame width and height
    frame_width = int(reader.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH ))
    frame_height = int(reader.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    frame_count = int(reader.get(7))
    fps =  int(reader.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
    print('frame_width, frame_height, frame_count, fps = ', frame_width, frame_height, frame_count, fps)

    # define codec and create VideoWriter object
    fourcc= cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')#*"MP4V")
    writer = cv2.VideoWriter(cropped_video , fourcc, 2, (frame_width, frame_height))

top = 20
botton= frame_height-20

count = 0

# read until end of video
while True:
    ret, frame = reader.read()
    if ret==True:
        cropped = frame[top:botton , :]
        frame = cv2.resize(cropped, (frame_width, frame_height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST_EXACT) 
        # save video frame
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(cropped_frames,"frame%d.jpg" % count), frame)
        writer.write(frame)
        count += 1
        print(count)
    else:
        break

            

# release VideoCapture()
reader.release()
writer.release()
# close all frames and video windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: how is the video, is it slow video or fast ? it happens on the slow video.

Comment: Its a slow video, downsampled at 2 frame per second. But why it is working on 1fps and 3 fps but not fps? The original video is also at 2fps so I was expecting VideoWriter to be able to regenerating the video on 2fps.

Comment: Executing your code sample, I am getting 2fps video file. Try replacing `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')` with `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')` (lower caps). You may use [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) tool for checking the framerate of `video_crop.mp4`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tested the *'mp4v' option and unfortunately that didn't work for me. Did you test with a 2fps video (input video at 2fps and output video at 2fps)? 
If so, then maybe something is wrong with the coding of my input?!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but when I opened it with vlc player (not the default video player on my Mac) the video looks fine, so maybe it's not an error in CV2. I've also played the video generated with other OS's computer, and it work fine well.

Comment: It could be improved by including more technical details or explanations.